# React Carousel with Multiple Items

Tags: reactjs, carousel, ternary-operator, react-bootstrap

I'm having problems with my slider with ternary conditions, how may I solve it?
It considers that i'm closing the item before the last clause is done. This is a trying of build a multi-item carousel.

```
<Carousel className="col-md-7 col-11" indicators="true" controls="false">
    {this.props.children.map((rooms,index) => 
        (index === 0 || index % 3 === 0) ? <Carousel.Item><h1>First</h1> : 
            ((index+1) % 3 === 0) ? <h1>Last</h1></Carousel.Item> : <h1>Middle</h1>
        )
    }
</Carousel>
```

Comment: What problems are you having? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this isn't valid JSX.

You can't render an opening `<Carousel.Item>` tag without a closing tag as part of the same expression. It's clear what you're trying to do here but it can't work because the JSX compiler can't 'know' that the closing tag will *ever* be rendered, because that's dependant on `children`. You *have* to render opening and closing tags as part of the same expression in order for the JSX to compile.

Probably the cleanest thing is to do the grouping of the `children` in a separate function and then map the result, simply rendering each group inside `<Carousel.Item></Carousel.Item>`, like so:

```
function groupIntoThrees (children) {
  const output = []
  let currentGroup = []

  children.forEach((child, index) => {
    currentGroup.push(child)

    if (index % 3 === 2) {
      output.push(currentGroup)
      currentGroup = []
    }
  })

  return output
}

... later in render method ...

<Carousel className="col-md-7 col-11" indicators="true" controls="false">
  {groupIntoThrees(this.props.children).map((group) => (
    <Carousel.Item>
      <h1>first: {group[0]}</h1>
      <h1>middle: {group[1]}</h1>
      <h1>last: {group[2]}</h1>
    </Carousel.Item>
  )} 
</Carousel>
```

Comment: But i'm doing it inside a map, this is the problem. I have to know what is the first and the last one to open and close the item. I'm trying to build a multi-item carousel.

Comment: I've to put 3 <h1> tags inside the same carousel item.

Comment: In that example if I have more then 3 <h1> it will continue rendering inside the same item.

Comment: @AndréGonçalves ah, glanced back at this today and now I've figured out what you were trying to do. So yes, the problem is you can't do it like you wanted, rendering an opening tag in one expression and then closing it later in another one, rendering other things in between. You have to first group the children and then render them all at once inside each item, with an opening and closing tag in the same expression.